# Is it safe to use 18650 battery pack for my setup?

Tags: batteries

I'm a beginner in FPV hobby.
I want to build a 18650 battery pack (4S1P), but I'm not sure what the right cells for me are.

Specs:

- I am using 4xMotors Xing 1404 3800kv which have a max continuous current is about 12A each.
- F4 AIO 20A

Will the Sony VTC6, with max discharge is 30A, be safe for this setup?

Comment: It all depends on the discharge current ratings of the 18650 cells you choose. You'll need the aforementioned rating to be above the maximum combined motor current. This should be true of both the peak current and sustained current draws. Without knowing more about the exact drone you're working on and how hard the motors will have to work, it's not really feasible to give a solid answer.

Comment: Yep thats why i ask if the sony vtc6 with max discharge 30A will fit with my setup ?

Comment: Well, what's the expected current draw of the drone? I hope not full power all the time...

Comment: Hi Mate if the answer is giving you the information you asked for, please accept it thanks

Comment: Important to note that the "max current" of the motor is not a limiter, it is the maximum current it can handle. Those motors will happily draw 30+ amps and blow themselves up if you put an 8 inch propeller on them. There are multirotor power calculators that can be used to get a sense for how much power your setup will draw

Answer (score 4):

Hi Mate those 18650 batteries are designed for general pourpouse usually the typical discharge current is Standard 0.5C Rapid 1.0C and the Max discharge current is 2C (for instance a 2200mA Battery will give you 1.1-2.2-5A Maximum- please see the data scheet here https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2144243.pdf ). Even the VTC6 is providing 20A max on the datasheet I have found here https://www.reichelt.com/de/en/industrial-cell-18650-3-6-v-3210-mah-unprotected-son-18650-vtc6-p261052.html : definetly not enough for your use. Please note that overdraining LiPo batteries will most likely drive into overheating-distruction of the battery and potentially very dangerous situations. If you are committed to design and build your own devices I would recommend to use dedicated batteries (seek for 20-30C ones at least).
What you are looking for is a good balance among battery weight, available current, flight endurance and most importantly of all SAFETY (you do not want your expensive drone falling from the sky over your Very expensive neighbour's car). It is very important to manage your charge/discharge/balance profiles using a dedicated battery charger/discharger. Store your batteries in proper LiPo Safe containers.
Be careful to manage LiPo batteries properly, in fact overcharging, shortcuts and using improperly those batteries may lead to fire, explosion and severe injuries.
Please use appropriate batteries, battery charger/discharger/balancer and procedures. I would recommend also to use a battery checker that will grant you that the battery is in proper conditions before, after and during the battery use. Be safe and enjoy your hobby. If you may need any help please ask. All the best